# what size does stat return while write?

Tags: linux-kernel, write

On Linux, suppose I do a `write()` to end of a file, and while this is still completing, from another thread I do a stat-type call on that file (such as `fstat()` or `lstat()`).

I would expect, that the stat-buffer `st_size` field during that time, would return between, the previous size of the file before the `write()`, and, the current size of valid data written already present in the file.  So that, if I were to use the `st_size` to `mmap()` the file with 0 offset, I will get valid data; perhaps not all the data yet, OK, but at least, all the previous contents of the file, plus perhaps some valid already written data.

Is that guaranteed ?

Comment: `stat` reads the inode of the file to determine the current size. So the question is not about the bytes written, but more about when the inode gets updated (it will be cached). I don't know, but I would not expect the inode to be updated other than at the end of a write operation, nor that all file systems (e.g. NTFS mounts) would work the same way, nor give any guarantees.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant so what you are saying, it is not guaranteed that `mmap()` will work correctly on whatever `st_size` is;  the only way to ensure that is to synchronise, `mmap()` has to wait until `write()` returns ?